# Create an activity to log in

Tags: php, android, kotlin

I am working on a Kotlin code with Android to create an Activity which checks the username and a password. I am using volley to do this. I am using this function in my MainActivity to do this :

```
private fun checking(){

        val name: String = editText?.text.toString()
        val password: String = editText2?.text.toString()

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 192.168.1.50,
                Response.Listener<String> {
                    response ->
                    try {
                        val obj = JSONObject(response)
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                object : Response.ErrorListener {
                    override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("name", name)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
```

And this is my php code :

```
<?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', '***');
define('PASS', '***');
define('DB', '***');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from *** where name = '$name' and password = '$password';";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($check)){
echo 'success';
}
else{
echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Actually what I want is just if I put the correct name and password so I will get in the Php `echo 'success';` I would like to have in my function `checking` a kind of Toast which will say successful connection. I try but I don't know how to modify my code. Thank you very much for your advices !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know `kotlin` but just in case you can make it out here is the `java` code for making the Toast.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successful connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
```

You will need to import `android.widget.Toast`
For more details and training visit the offcial site [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

**Edit**
Well I already said I dont know kotlin but maybe try this code.

```
private fun checking(){

        val name: String = editText?.text.toString()
        val password: String = editText2?.text.toString()
        val temp: String ="pass"  //Creating a new string I dont know if it is dont this way


        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 192.168.1.50,
                Response.Listener<String> {
                    response ->
                    try {
                        val obj = JSONObject(response)
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                object : Response.ErrorListener {
                    override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        temp="fail" //Setting the temp string to fail. dont know if it dont this way either
                    }
                }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("name", name)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }
        if(temp.isEqual("pass")) // checkig if temp was changed or not
        {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successful connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
        }
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
```

Please dont point out if my synatx is wrong. I dont know the K of Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks but where can I have to add this in my code ?

Comment: Edited. Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case To make a `Toast` in `Kotlin` Syntax is:

```
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,obj.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

replace this line with your existing Toast Line